# Shortest path tool failed in QGIS

Tags: qgis, point, shortest-path

I'm trying to find the shortest path between two points (green and red points) on a road layer using QGIS 2.12.3. The roads layer has appropriate CRS.

[image]

Before sign the "start" and "end" points I approximate to the crossing lines, in order to sign exact points

[image]

[image]

But I get no result

[image]

[image]

Comment: are you using a plugin? is your topology correct? http://docs.qgis.org/2.0/en/docs/user_manual/plugins/plugins_topology_checker.html

Comment: yes, i using the plugin

Comment: What is your CRS? http://docs.qgis.org/1.8/en/docs/user_manual/plugins/plugins_road_graph.html

Comment: Can you share the road data for test purposes?

Comment: yes, how can i upload the roads layer?